# Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm a big enthusiast about new Zend Framework. I had done one project in the previous version so far and I decided to learn new one which contains a really hard parts to understand for me.

I've watched webinars and youtube videos, also I read the documentation and I'm trying to understand this framework simply by read the code but there are few things I just can't figure out.

There is a lot information about `EventManager` in webinars but since I'm lack at English I'm just not able to understand 100% of the speech.

I know that event manager manage events which is quite obvious but I don't really know how to use it: in one of the webinars they provide some simple examples but they don't explain where to put this code, is it `module.php` file? Or some other place if you can show me some practical example with explanation so i can see whats the point.

Next thing is that mysterious `$e` passed as an argument to most of the functions in `Module.php` which after is used like this: `$e->getApplication` or something I just wonder what this `$e` stands for? It is instance of what? And next thing is how it is passed "automatically" to these functions?

Another problem: in configuration files which are specified for each module called `module.config.php` there is a lot of things. I got the point of routes I've understood them but I can't figure out what are the invokables and factories. It is also explained in one of the webinars as follow: invokables are paths to classes, factories are callable functions or classes (cant remember). The point is OK, that make sense in some theoretical talk but please provide me some examples with in depth explanation, where those factories and invokables come from and other stuff that I need to know.

The other thing is that there is a lot of configuration possibilities in those configuration files. Where can I find some informations about what `"keys"=>"values"` are possible in those files?

That's all for now but there are still unanswered questions i would like to ask. If someone is able to help me, I would really appreciate to correspond via mail with this person.

---

Ok one problem is solved. The one about mysterious &e so if somene is intersted in here is a solution:

This $e variable instance depends on what function we use in module.php file:

case 1: init() -> &e is an instance of module manager
case 2: onBootstrap() -> &e is an instance of MvcEvent
(if there are other cases i havent found please let us know)

The thing is that those methods are called when event has been triggered so mysterious &e is passed to those functions by listenerers which are listening if these functions appears in our code (this is my simple logic of that so please dont hate me)

There are still other questions to answer.. as soon as ill figure out some senseful answer i will let you know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within stock ZF2 code, `$e` is always an instance of `Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface`. Usually it is either an `Zend\EventManager\Event` or an `Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent`.

A class' EventManager triggers an event which results in listener callbacks being called. Each listener callback is passed an instance of an `Event` which then has some useful methods, notably `getTarget()` and `getParams()`. Other instances of `EventManagerInterface` usually have more specialised methods. `MvcEvent` in particular has methods related to the `Mvc` component, such as `getApplication()`, `getRouter()`, `getRequest()` and `getResponse()`.

Comment: Could you please also explain when it is Zend\EventManager\Event and when Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent?

Comment: You get an MvcEvent only from events triggered by the Zend\Mvc component.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information about tghe EventManager, application configuration and MvcEvent in the "Using Zend Framework 2" book: http://leanpub.com/using-zend-framework-2